# Can the attraction between two oppositely charged black holes exceed the proposed force limit $c^4/4G$?

Tags: general-relativity, electrostatics, black-holes, charge, event-horizon

1. Given two black holes (not rotating) of masses $M$ and $m$,
   and (opposite) charges $Q$ and $-q$, what is their total force of attraction (gravity and electrostatic)? An answer for extremally charged black holes would be sufficient.
2. Is this total force of attraction ever larger than $c^4/4G$? For example, when one black hole is much larger than the other and when these two black holes are as close as possible?

The aim is to understand how gravitational and electrostatic force combine. My intuition is that the total force is not larger than the value $c^4/4G$. But I do not know how to calculate the total attraction. My guess is that the electrostatic energy changes the two horizons, and that in this way the problem reduces to the uncharged case, but with different horizon radii. In the uncharged case, the force of attraction between two Schwarzschild black holes, whatever their radii or masses, is never larger than $c^4/4G$, as shown by G. Gibbons. So my guess is that this limit is also valid for charged black holes.

The idea would be to lower a test mass with a rope towards the black hole, and to measure the force at the rope. The nearer the test mass is to the horizon, the higher the force.  And the more concentrated the test mass becomes, the higher the force.

For an extremally charged Reissner–Nordström black hole, the Schwarzschild radius is reduced. The horizon remains spherically symmetric. It seems that the force between two such black holes is still limited by $c^4/4G$.

The force value $c^4/4G$ has been called by some the maximum force value in nature. So the calculation checks whether the maximum is also valid if gravity and electrostatics are combined, or whether such a combination allows to exceed the alleged maximum value: the calculation is a way to settle one of the paradoxes that arise when exploring the force limit of $c^4/4G$.

The force concept remains tricky in general relativity. Therefore, you can replace, in this discussion, force $F$ by momentum rate $\text{d}p/\text{d}t$, which is always well-defined also in general relativity.

P.S. This is not a homework question at all; I'm 51 years old, and the question is triggered by a remark from reddit. It is a question to check the concept of maximum force proposed by G. Gibbons from the University of Cambridge.

P.S.2. A researcher told me that several papers on the maximum force will be published in the coming months. These papers will show that the maximum force holds in nature. He will send me the references. He also told me that the maximum force is not so well known yet, and that I should be patient.

Comment: Hi! What do you think? What attempts have you made in answering these questions? Please explain in your question above in detail.

Comment: Gravity is not a real force in GR.

Comment: I added details for both comments.

Comment: @Christian This paper gives some counterexamples of the maximum force hypothesis. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.01831.pdf. The examples given are in perfect fluids.

Comment: I found a comment about it on https://www.motionmountain.net/street.html#R4 on the last line.

Comment: I added everything I could to make the question clear and interesting. It is still closed for being homework-like. Sad!

Comment: I am unconvinced there is anything fundamentally interesting to be obtained from limits on the magnitude of a three vector, but at the same time this is clearly not homework and is a genuine area of research. See for example [Schiller's paper here](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0607090). The question should be reopened.

Comment: @Christian if you drop an object into a black hole and watch it from far away then the speed of the object first increases then decreases again when the object gets to 1.5 Schwardzschild radii and the object slows to a halt at the horizon. There are numerous questions on the site relating to this. Anyhow the result of this is that the acceleration at first increases then decreases, and the maximum acceleration is indeed of of order $c^4/G$. But I must emphasise this is the acceleration **as seen by the external observer** and this is a coordinate dependent quantity.

Comment: Different observers will measure different gravitational accelerations. For example an observer hovering at a fixed distance from the black hole measures the acceleration to increase to infinity as that observer approaches the horizon. In this case the limit of $c^4/GM$ does not apply. Although there is a sense in which this limit exists there is nothing especially physically meaningful about it.

Comment: @John, no the force will not go to infinity. The body that is let down is itself at least as large as a black hole. If you take this minimum size into account (giving a minimum distance to the horizon), the force is never larger than c^4/4G.

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy  The latest paper on $c^4/4G$ as maximum force is C. Schiller, Comment on "Maximum force and cosmic censorship", Physical Review D 104 (2021) 068501, preprint at [arxiv.org/abs/2109.07700](http://arxiv.org/abs/2109.07700).

Comment: A new paper on the topic: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.124079